# how to retrieve a document with no nulls at all in pymongo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I want to get a document with no nulls at all, without specifying a certain column

I tried something like that to sort by bigger values for certain column

> coll1.find({}).sort("slots", -1)

However, I still have to specify a column name which is something i want to avoid

sample:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"60a76f36ad6bc67a5bac2329"},"timings":[{"_id":{"$oid":"60a76f59ef72a67a84a32593"},"starttime":{"$date":"2000-02-01T05:00:00.000Z"},"endtime":{"$date":"2000-02-01T09:00:00.000Z"},"isslotbased":false,"duration":40,"noofslots":1,"tokenprefix":null},{"_id":{"$oid":"60a76f59ef72a67a84a32592"},"starttime":{"$date":"2000-02-01T09:30:00.000Z"},"endtime":{"$date":"2000-02-01T12:15:00.000Z"},"isslotbased":false,"duration":40,"noofslots":1,"tokenprefix":null}],"slots":[{"_id":{"$oid":"60adea5f1164e10862ad5478"},"patientuid":{"$oid":"6028f4c5cf2c7e189f0e68ee"},"title":"FATIMAH (3200000000684)","description":"FATIMAH","priorityuid":{"$oid":"56cb4f5013ab1595bae1d89d"},"statusuid":{"$oid":"56f91847b5c3bf9ec2dc7ff1"},"backgroundcolor":"Cyan","visittypeuid":{"$oid":"5bf4f9581a1d357b2e8e4d5c"},"start":{"$date":"2021-06-23T10:10:00.000Z"},"end":{"$date":"2021-06-23T10:50:00.000Z"},"expirydate":null,"allDay":false,"modeuid":null,"smstextuid":null,"isactive":true,"comments":"UNK","statusreason":"","refererdetail":null,"appointmentnumber":"32A2105260033","externalappointmentnumber":"11636041250009","bookedbyuseruid":{"$oid":"5fd51c796f568c5d8c739326"},"orderdetails":"","servicetypeuid":null,"bookthroughportal":false,"isteleconsult":false,"teleconsultlink":"","auditlog":[{"_id":{"$oid":"60adea5f1164e10862ad547a"},"useruid":{"$oid":"5fd51c796f568c5d8c739326"},"statusuid":{"$oid":"56f91847b5c3bf9ec2dc7ff1"},"modifiedat":{"$date":"2021-05-26T06:27:43.485Z"},"reasonuid":null,"comments":"Updated from vendor application"}],"patientcareteams":[]},{"_id":{"$oid":"60adeb524ec3fe6c89100b25"},"patientuid":{"$oid":"60aa5d9d34156d54125d79e9"},"title":"OSAMA (3200000003410)","description":"OSAMA","priorityuid":{"$oid":"56cb4f5013ab1595bae1d89d"},"statusuid":{"$oid":"56f91847b5c3bf9ec2dc7ff1"},"backgroundcolor":"Cyan","visittypeuid":{"$oid":"5bf4f9581a1d357b2e8e4d5c"},"start":{"$date":"2021-06-23T05:00:00.000Z"},"end":{"$date":"2021-06-23T05:40:00.000Z"},"expirydate":null,"allDay":false,"modeuid":null,"smstextuid":null,"isactive":true,"comments":"UNK","statusreason":"","refererdetail":null,"appointmentnumber":"32A2105260035","externalappointmentnumber":"11503639900004","bookedbyuseruid":{"$oid":"5fd51c796f568c5d8c739326"},"orderdetails":"","servicetypeuid":null,"bookthroughportal":false,"isteleconsult":false,"teleconsultlink":"","auditlog":[{"_id":{"$oid":"60adeb524ec3fe6c89100b27"},"useruid":{"$oid":"5fd51c796f568c5d8c739326"},"statusuid":{"$oid":"56f91847b5c3bf9ec2dc7ff1"},"modifiedat":{"$date":"2021-05-26T06:31:46.783Z"},"reasonuid":null,"comments":"Updated from vendor application"}],"patientcareteams":[]},{"_id":{"$oid":"60ae0d4da9001568c9231a89"},"patientuid":{"$oid":"60ae0d4da9001568c9231a86"},"title":"WEJDAN (3200000003705)","description":"WEJDAN","priorityuid":{"$oid":"56cb4f5013ab1595bae1d89d"},"statusuid":{"$oid":"56f91847b5c3bf9ec2dc7ff1"},"backgroundcolor":"Cyan","visittypeuid":{"$oid":"5bf4f9581a1d357b2e8e4d5c"},"start":{"$date":"2021-06-23T10:50:00.000Z"},"end":{"$date":"2021-06-23T11:30:00.000Z"},"expirydate":null,"allDay":false,"modeuid":null,"smstextuid":null,"isactive":true,"comments":"UNK","statusreason":"","refererdetail":null,"appointmentnumber":"32A2105260058","externalappointmentnumber":"11108722050001","bookedbyuseruid":{"$oid":"5fd51c796f568c5d8c739326"},"orderdetails":"","servicetypeuid":null,"bookthroughportal":false,"isteleconsult":false,"teleconsultlink":"","auditlog":[{"_id":{"$oid":"60ae0d4da9001568c9231a8b"},"useruid":{"$oid":"5fd51c796f568c5d8c739326"},"statusuid":{"$oid":"56f91847b5c3bf9ec2dc7ff1"},"modifiedat":{"$date":"2021-05-26T08:56:45.402Z"},"reasonuid":null,"comments":"Updated from vendor application"}],"patientcareteams":[]}],"appointmentsessionuid":{"$oid":"60a75c82ef72a67a84a3238b"},"appointmentslotdetailsuid":{"$oid":"60a75c82ef72a67a84a3238c"},"appointmentdate":{"$date":"2021-06-23T00:00:00.000Z"},"generatedby":{"$oid":"60810944626f13115df806f6"},"careprovideruid":null,"departmentuid":{"$oid":"6013b278ad83796154f730a7"},"departmentbasedschedule":true,"clinicbasedschedule":false,"defaultduration":5,"clinicuid":null,"iscancelled":false,"createdby":{"$oid":"60810944626f13115df806f6"},"createdat":{"$date":"2021-05-21T08:28:38.822Z"},"modifiedby":{"$oid":"60810944626f13115df806f6"},"modifiedat":{"$date":"2021-05-26T08:56:45.404Z"},"statusflag":"A","orguid":{"$oid":"5fe34a55aa395cf86cd4bea2"},"__v":3,"modifycomments":null,"modifyreasonuid":{"$oid":"59647640c79fa1352bd5cbee"}}
```

Comment: can you show the sample document, is there any field containing an object or array?

Comment: i added a a sample

Comment: there are lots of fields in a document, this is not a good idea to do this in mongodb.

Comment: what about a python script?

Comment: yes you can, but i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in python with a function like:

```
def no_nulls(dic):
    for k, v in list(dic.items()):
        if v is None:
            del dic[k]
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for items in v:
                no_nulls(items)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            no_nulls(v)

    return dic
```